# Will deleting a branch mess up a new branch created from it?

Tags: git

Here's how my repo looks like now:

[image]

I created branch `i449` from `develop` some time ago to work on an issue. Then I realized that I had made some changes that belonged to another issue, so I created the branch `i447` from `i449`.

I finished working on the initial issue so I have now merged `i449` into `develop` and pushed the changes (`git push origin develop`). Now I would like to delete the `i449` branch, since it serves no purpose anymore. My fear is that, since `i447` was created from it, deleting `i449` will mess up `i447` which contains important changes.

What will happen to `i447` if I do thi
s?

```
# Delete remote branch
git push origin --delete i449
# Delete local branch
git branch -d i449
```

Is this the proper way to handle this?

---

For the sake of completeness, here's how the repo looks after deleting `i449`:

[image]

Now my doubt is what will happen when I try to merge `i447` into `develop`, but I guess I'll see.

Comment: Nothing will happen.  Delete at will.

Comment: Note, by the way, that if those images are from GitHub's "network graph" (they look like they are), they're full of errors and weirdness. Don't take them too literally.

Comment: @torek indeed they are. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can safely delete the branch `i449`, this won't change anything to the history of your `i447` branch.

Each **branch** is only a **reference** to a git commit. Your branch `i447` still refers to its own commit, which won't change.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that will be deleted here is the reference named `i449`, **not** the commits it now happens to reference.

Since these commits still are part of the tree and referenced through 1) the merge commit you made on `develop` and 2) the `i447` branch itself, they keep being referenced so they will stay.

Go for it.

Comment: The commits made on `i449` are already pushed. What I don't know is what will happen to `i447` after I delete `i449`? Will it be attached to `develop`?

Answer (score 1):

Nope.... you can delete them at will... branches are just pointers to revisions so they can be created/moved around/deleted..... if you have a branch pointed to a later revision, that won't be affected by deleting the branch.

Comment: Where will `i447` end up after deleting `i449`?

Comment: Right where it is... it won t move.